# How to show scroll idicator above modal bottom sheet flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a scroll indicator above a modal bottom sheet in flutter. I was thinking about using divider, or a rounded container. See the image on top of the bottom sheet. I've tried several ways to accomplish this, however, i cant get it to work. See my code below.

[image]

Showing the sheet:

```
onPressedAddDog() {
showModalBottomSheet(
  enableDrag: true,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      topRight: Radius.circular(40),
    ),
  ),
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AddDogModalSheet();
  },
);
```

}

Then here is the content of the sheet (aka AddDogModoalSheet from the function above).

```
 class AddDogModalSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (518 / 812),
              child: Column(),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The way I've tried to do it now is with a stack, however, the divider does not position itself over the sheeet. Also, i tried wrapping it with Positioned (since the sheet and divider are in a stack). However, then the divider dissapeared. the current code produces this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how i can accomplish whats on the first picture, with a white "scroll indicator" above the sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!

My code:

Set the modal background to transparent. And the content as column:

```
onPressedAddDog() {
showModalBottomSheet(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (518 / 812),
    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (518 / 812),
  ),
  enableDrag: true,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      topRight: Radius.circular(40),
    ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AddDogModalSheet();
  },
);
```

}

```
    class AddDogModalSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 5,
            width: 52,
            color: Colors.black,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                topRight: Radius.circular(40),
              ),
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```